# I'm trying to make text box in javascript, and to send the entered values in a textbox in a array to add them

Tags: javascript, arrays

Created textbox in javascript, need those value to pass in arrays to add them ?
how do I do that ?
I just want my code to be short and simple

I'm stuck!
Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> 2 NUM ADD VIA ARRAY </title>
    </head>     
    <body bgcolor= "red" </body>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function sum()
    {
    var sum = [],i=0;


    sum[i]=  document.getElementById('i+1').value;

    alert("sum =" + sum);
    }
    </script>   
    <table border=2>
            <TR>
                <TD>

                    <input type="text" id="1" /input>

                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <input type="text" id="2" /input>
                </TD>
            </TR>
    </table>

    <button name="btHello" onclick="sum();">sum</button>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usage of Array in this case is not required according to me.I suggest you to do this even without using arrays. This makes your code simple and short

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title> 2 NUM ADD VIA ARRAY </title>
        </head>     
        <body bgcolor= "red" </body>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
        function sum()
        {
              var sum= 0; 
             $('.textbox').each(function() {
                sum += Number($(this).val());
              });
              alert(sum);    
        }
        </script>   
        <form>
        <table border=2>
                <TR>
                    <TD>

                        Text 1 :<input type="text" class="textbox" id="1" />

                    </TD>
                    <TD>
                        Text 2 :<input type="text" class="textbox" id="2" />
                    </TD>
                </TR>
        </table>

        Submit : <input type = "submit" name="btHello" onclick="sum();">
        </form>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope my example helps. I suggest using jQuery. It makes it much easier.

```js
function foo() {
    var s = [];
    $(".foo").each(function() {
        s.push( $(this).val() );
    });
    s = s.join(" ");
    alert("sum = " + s);
}

$("#btHello").on("click", function() { foo(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=2>
    <tr>
        <td>
            
            <input type="text" class="foo" /input>
                
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="foo" /input>
                </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<button id="btHello">sum</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m to totally sure what result you want, but this should help you on your way. If its not totally what you are after, please try to explain your goal a bit more. :)

Happy codin'

```js
    function sum()
    {
        
var sum = [];
    sum.push(document.getElementById('1').value);
    sum.push(document.getElementById('2').value);

// sum of all values
totalSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
    totalSum += parseInt(sum[i]);
}
    alert("sum = " + totalSum);
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> 2 NUM ADD VIA ARRAY </title>
    </head>     
    <body bgcolor= "red" </body>

   
    <table border=2>
            <TR>
                <TD>

                    <input type="text" id="1" /input>

                </TD>
                <TD>
                    <input type="text" id="2" /input>
                </TD>
            </TR>
    </table>

    <button name="btHello" onclick="sum();">sum</button>

</html>
```